# Foucault and scientific revolutions

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, foucault

In the famous debate between Foucault and Chomsky ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TUD4gfvtDY)), Foucault argues that there is no human nature really because, among other things, a scientific revolution in some science is just a revolution in the language used by the science in question.

What interests me is Foucault's view of scientific revolutions and specially its relation with linguistics, not his arguments about human nature. Where can I find more about his philosophy of scientific revolutions? Did he develop this kind of thought only in that debate or did he write about it? Forgive me if this is a naive question, but I could not easily find the answer.

Comment: For some background, see [Scientific Revolutions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-revolutions/), and [Michel Foucault's Immature Science](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2214794?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and [Scientific Change](https://www.iep.utm.edu/s-change/).

Comment: Foucault's word is "episteme" and its main use is seen in *Les mots et les choses*. A few years later in l'*Archeologie du savoir* he used '"archive". It was only the late 60's that he was interested in this topic; see e.g. O'Farrell's book *Foucault: historian or philosopher* .